# When I paste text, it can't get height of text

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, string, text

When I paste text, I got wrong height of text. It don't count it. I can get only height of first line. However, if I click return key, each line of text like "Software\nis\nawesome", it work well. here is code:

```
let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18)!
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 8

let textFontAttributes = [
     NSFontAttributeName: font,
     NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 0.149, green: 0.149, blue: 0.145, alpha: 1.00),
     NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle
     ] as [String : Any]

let string:NSString = NSString(string: self.txtView.text)
let size:CGSize = string.size(attributes: textFontAttributes)
print("size.height")
```

But, when I did typing some text, I can get correct height of text.

How can I get correct height of text?

Comment: @returntrue what is the meaning..? I put code below

Answer (score 0):

put your code in

```
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
       let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18)!
    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 8

    let textFontAttributes = [
         NSFontAttributeName: font,
         NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 0.149, green: 0.149, blue: 0.145, alpha: 1.00),
         NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyle
         ] as [String : Any]

    let string:NSString = NSString(string: self.txtView.text)
    let size:CGSize = string.size(attributes: textFontAttributes)
    print("size.height")
    return true;
 }
```

You can also use

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
      let size = self.textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: width_you_can_afford, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. first code is same result. It mean change height when I paste text. second code is changed value, but it is different height compare to correct height :(